# Passing variables from controller to view in php

Tags: php

I am building a php framework (MVC) for learning purposes. i need help with sending variables from my controller to the view.

**HomeController**

```
<?php
class HomeController{
    public function home()
    {
        $some_var = "Do Something";
        return view("home.php",compact('some_var'));
    }
}
?>
```

I want to be able to access the `$some_var` variable in my view

**view**

```
<h3>$some_var</h3>
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: would like suggest you SMARTY template to pass controller data to view files.  See this link for how to integrate SMARTY with your code http://codesamplez.com/development/smarty-basics-tutorial

Comment: Is this laravel framework or you try to build your custom framework?

Comment: @Md. Sahadat Hossain  a custom one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the variables from the controller accessible in the html file, you get the variables from the `compact` function using php's `extract` function [extract function documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) before including the html file

```
   <?php

// Controller Class

class Controller
{
    public function someMethod()
    {
        $variable = "SomeVar";
        return view("home.php",compact('variable'));
    }
}

// template loader

function view($page,$variables=[])
{
    if(count($variables))
    {
        extract($variables);
    }
    require $page;
}
```

this makes `$variable` accessible in the `index.php` file

Answer (score 0):

You will get basic idea how `view()` function load data from the following.

Read this manual how codeigniter load view file from [here.](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/loader.html) And how internally `$this->load->view('view', $data);` the `view()` function works see the following code

```
public function view($view, $vars = array(), $return = FALSE)
{
    return $this->_ci_load(array('_ci_view' => $view, '_ci_vars' => $this->_ci_prepare_view_vars($vars), '_ci_return' => $return));
}
```

> Detail of `public function view()` function is from [here.](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/core/Loader.php)

Comment: This answer is giving CodeIgniter advice, but the asker is rolling their own MVC.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
class HomeController{
    public function home()
    {
        $some_var = "Do Something";
        return view("home")->with('some_var',$some_var);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: It would be great if you'd not only just drop some code, but also give an explanation of what is going on in his and your code. It helps the question author and other users. It's good if it works, but knowing **why** is even more important in my opinion.