# I have this small mvc that adds members to database and associate them with one or multiple school and has many to many relationship

Tags: php, mysql, model-view-controller

I have 3 folders: one for controller (index.php), one for model (database.php), and one for view (view.php).

My code is working fine in controller and model. I added some `var_dumps` to be sure that I can get list of schools from the database, but in my views I can't see the list of schools in my dropdowns.

Below is the code for index.php:

```
<?php
require_once '../model/database.php';
require '../view/view.php';
$db = new Database('localhost', 'mydb', 'root', '');

if (!empty($_POST)) {
    var_dump($_POST);
}
if (!empty($_POST) && isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    // Add new member
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $school = $_POST['school'];
    $db->addMember($name, $email, $school);
}

// Get list of schools
$schools = $db->getSchools();

// Get members for selected school
$selectedSchool = isset($_GET['school']) ? $_GET['school'] : null;
$members = [];
if ($selectedSchool) {
    $members = $db->getMembersBySchool($selectedSchool);
}
```

and this is database.php:

```
 <?php

class Database
{
    private $pdo;

    public function __construct($host, $dbname, $username, $password)
    {
        try {
            $dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname";
            $this->pdo = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
            $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }
        $dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname";
        $this->pdo = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
        $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }

    public function addMember($name, $email, $school)
    {
        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO members (name, email) VALUES (:name, :email)");
        $stmt->execute([':name' => $name, ':email' => $email]);
        $memberId = $this->pdo->lastInsertId();

        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO member_schools (member_id, school_id) VALUES (:member_id, :school_id)");
        $stmt->execute([':member_id' => $memberId, ':school_id' => $school]);
    }

    public function getSchools()
    {

        try {
            $stmt = $this->pdo->query("SELECT * FROM schools");
            $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            return $result;
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo 'Query failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }

        return $result;
    }

    public function getMembersBySchool($school)
    {
        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT members.* FROM members JOIN member_schools ON members.id = member_schools.member_id WHERE member_schools.school_id = :school_id");
        $stmt->execute([':school_id' => $school]);
        return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
}
```

and finally here is my view:

```
<!-- Form to add new member -->
<form method="post">
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" required>
    <br>
    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required>
    <br>
    <label for="school">School:</label>
    <select name="school" id="school" required>
        <?php foreach ($schools as$school): ?>
            <option value="<?= htmlspecialchars($school['id']) ?>"><?= htmlspecialchars($school['name']) ?></option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add Member">
</form>

<!-- Form to select school -->
<form method="get">
    <label for="select-school">Select School:</label>
    <select name="school" id="select-school">
        <?php foreach ($schools as$school): ?>
            <option value="<?= htmlspecialchars($school['id']) ?>"<?= ($selectedSchool ==$school['id']) ? ' selected' : '' ?>><?= htmlspecialchars($school['name']) ?></option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Select">
</form>

<!-- Display members for selected school -->
<?php if ($selectedSchool): ?>
<h2>Members for <?= htmlspecialchars($schools[array_search($selectedSchool, array_column($schools, 'id'))]['name']) ?>:</h2>
<ul>
    <?php foreach ($members as$member): ?>
        <li><?= htmlspecialchars($member['name']) ?> (<?= htmlspecialchars($member['email']) ?>)</li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
<?php endif;?>
```

The list of schools should display in the dropdown and it should post data to the database. I added `var_dumps` to be sure that list of schools are coming in the controller `$schools = $db->getSchools(); var_dump($schools)` and it shows expected data

Comment: It seems like your controller doesn't returning any value, try to return it with return $schools

Comment: no luck @AousMohammad

Comment: It looks like you're requiring your view before you actually define the `$schools` variable. You'll need to run your fetches before you display the view.

Comment: Checking `!empty($_POST)` is the same as checking `$_POST`.  It is a superglobal and is always declared.  I recommend skipping that check and relying on the next `isset()` only.  `isset($_GET['school']) ? $_GET['school'] : null` is `$_GET['school'] ?? null`

Comment: As Darren said, your require view.php line is at the top of the script.  This means that your view scripts are executing before the controller part.  Try moving the require '../view/view.php'; line to the last line of your index.php file.

Comment: I moved require at the bottom of the file but still it’s not populating drop-downs @Darren

Comment: [Passing variables from controller to view in php](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42782044/2943403)

Comment: I see you're using short tags (`<?=`) - do you have this enabled on your PHP? Could you chuck error reporting on at the top of your script and see if anything shows up? (`ini_set('display_errors', 1);error_reporting(-1);`)

Answer (score 0):

If you require a file that is not just a class definition (any PHP file that is supposed to execute from the top down), then it is the same as if you copy and pasted the contents of that file right into the place where the require statement is, and that entire file executes right there, in that order.